# Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined send

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So this code I'm using isn't really working and I would really appreciate it if someone helped me the details are under the code.

````
  name: "randompassword",
  aliases: ["randompass", "password", "pass"],
  description: "Sends a random password",
  async execute(client, message) {
    let password = [];
let possible ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+'
let passString
let passWordLength = 20;
for (let i = 0; i < passWordLength; i++) {
    password.push(possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)));
}
passString = password.join('') 
    return message.author
        .send(passString)

        .then(() => {
          if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return
          message.reply({
            content: "I've sent you a DM with the randomized password!",
          })
  })
 }
}```

It's not really working and its saying `Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') I would appreciate it if you guys can help :)) (I'm new to coding pls go easy on me xD). I'm a new discord.js developer soooooo yeah. Thanks in Advanced! Have a great day uwuw. Anyways do you guys like nuggets?
````

Comment: Your `message.author` property is `undefined`. If `message.author` is `undefined`, you cannot call a method `.send` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to send data directly to the `author` property without any checks. First of all, [`author` property is nullable inside `Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=author). You should check, if author is exist at all on this object and then try to send the message. Secondly, I have suspicion, that you'll be unable to send anything if user do not accept DMs from anyone. I suggest you to look at [`User#createDM` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=createDM), which will return a `DMChannel` for you to deal with.

```js
{
  async execute(client, message) {
    const author = message.author;
    
    if (!author) {
      // Maybe tell user that something went wrong 
      // and you can't get the author

      return;
    }
    
    // Trying to send the message to the user with the password.
    try {
      const dmChannel = await author.createDM();

      await dmChannel.send({content: "Your password here!"});
    } catch (error) {
      // Probably should tell that you can't send the DM
      // message. User should check if he opened his DM for
      // anyone.
    }
    
  }
}
```

Also, as an additional note: if you using latest versions of `discord.js`, you should probably start using new format for `send` methods as described in the guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc).

Comment: Thank youu, I'll make sure to read the guide!